# Creating LUIS APP Programmatically Python SDK

Tags: python, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I have gone through the LUIS Documentation and I was able to train and Publish my Luis APP as shown [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-python-sdk-samples/tree/master/samples/language/luis).
In my ChatBot(Bot Framework v4) I am using Dispatcher to breakdown the Luis into its respective groups.

The Intent, Utterance, and Entities are sourced from an external Database. I want to handle "Create", "Train" and "Publish" of LUIS APP's programmatically so, if a new "Intent Group" is created, this would create a basic intent in the "Base Luis" and "New Child LUIS" based on the new "Intent Group".

While the example shows Training and Publishing an Existing LUIS APP, It still doesn't show how to "Create" a LUIS APP Programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample of LUIS app creation in the link you mentioned:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-python-sdk-samples/blob/master/samples/language/luis/luis_authoring_samples.py#L29

```
# Create a LUIS app
default_app_name = "Contoso-{}".format(datetime.datetime.now())
version_id = "0.1"

print("Creating App {}, version {}".format(default_app_name, version_id))

app_id = client.apps.add({
    'name': default_app_name,
    'initial_version_id': version_id,
    'description': "New App created with LUIS Python sample",
    'culture': 'en-us',
})
print("Created app {}".format(app_id))
```

Where `client` is

```
client = LUISAuthoringClient(
    'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com',
    CognitiveServicesCredentials(subscription_key),
)
```